# Creating an element in a namespace in Dart

Tags: dart

I am trying to create an element in a particular namespace in Dart. Is this the best way to do it:

```
document.$dom_createElementNS(namespace, tag);
```

Documentation [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Document.html#%24dom_createElementNS).

Additionally is there a particular reason for the $ sign in the function name?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a quote from Pete Blois](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/misc/Ps7mL2HoO3o/rta534lMY7kJ) (emphasis mine):

> As part of our API cleanup process, we're planning on converting all of the DOM `$dom_` APIs to be private.
>
> **These APIs have been available as lower-level alternatives to existing APIs, but their use has not been recommended.**
>
> Please let us know if you are using any of the `$dom_` APIs and why, we'd like to fix those up before making this change.

However, I can't find an equivalent of this function in the existing APIs. So consider his last sentence by [posting your question in the thread](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/Ps7mL2HoO3o/discussion) or [filing an issue](http://dartbug.com/new).